# PHP throwing out an error version mismatch with MySQL plugin

Tags: debian, php

I am using Debian Jessie here, and I have got a couple of PHP pages showing the error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli::real_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50553 Library:50630

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
```

The `php5` package is `5.6.30+dfsg-0+deb8u1`.
The `php5-mysql` package is `5.6.30+dfsg-0+deb8u1`.

Both are standard Debian packages, and I have not compiled by hand any part of the components.

I tried apt update and upgrade, reinstalling `php5-mysql`, and restarting Apache, but it did not solve the problem.

`phpinfo()` also complains about mismatched versions in `php5-mysql`.

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a bug packaging `php5-mysql`; I found a related question in this post [Headers and client library minor version mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759334/headers-and-client-library-minor-version-mismatch).

While not the accepted answer, the most pertinent answer in that link is:

> For new MySQL 5.6 family you need to install php5-mysqlnd, not
>   php5-mysql.
>
> Remove this version of the mysql driver
>
> sudo apt-get remove php5-mysql And install this instead
>
> sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd

However, for maintaining the consistency of dependencies, uninstalling `php5-mysql` is not the best of the ideas; it is much better doing:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

And letting the dependencies uninstall `php5-mysql` *while* installing `php5-mysqlnd`.

From packages.debian.org: [Package: php5-mysqlnd](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/php5-mysqlnd)

> MySQL module for php5 (Native Driver)
>
> This package provides modules for MySQL database connections directly
>   from PHP scripts. It includes the generic "mysql" module which can be
>   used to connect to all versions of MySQL, an improved "mysqli" module
>   for MySQL version 4.1 or later, and the pdo_mysql module for use with
>   the PHP Data Object extension.

After doing `sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd`, the pages in question started working normally, without giving that warning.

However, other legacy pages in another of the pages still using `latin1` / iso-8859-1 started displayed funny letters e.g. being forced to UTF-8, so we had to rollback on that server to `php5-mysql`.